# EF: Include properties on condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a type `ContentEntry` and some classes that inherit from it. Some of these classes implement an interface that requires an property `ICollection<T> LanguageSpecificItems`. The type of T depends on the type of the sub class. These properties are mapped into my database. That is no problem at all.

My problem is that I have a `ICollection<ContentEntry>` as a property of another class. But I need to get the `LanguageSpecificItems` sub-list if it exists to proceed some things with an abstract method of `ContentEntry`. If I call `.Include` on my `DbSet<MyOtherClass>` it does not work.

```
MyDbSet.Include("LanguageSpecificItems")...
```

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Koopakiller.Website.Model.ContentEntry' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'LanguageSpecificItems'.

But it exists in some inherited classes, and if it does not exists I does not need it.

How can I solve this issue?

**UPDATE: CODE**

This is a part of my `DbContext:

```
public partial class CommonDbModel : DbContext
{
    public CommonDbModel() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
```

Account has a property with `ContentEntry`s:

```
public class Account : IUser<Guid>
{
    public virtual ICollection<ContentEntry> CommentEmailSubscriptions { get; set; }
```

And `ContentEntry` has a Collection of Àccount` for the subscriptions:

```
public abstract class ContentEntry : ISearchResult
{
    public virtual ICollection<Account> CommentEmailSubscriptions { get; set; }

    public abstract LocalizedSearchResult GetLocalizedPart();
```

The `GetLocalizedPart` is implemented in the sub-classes and access in some cases the `LanguageSpecificItems` property if the class implements the interface:

```
public class BlogEntry : ContentEntry, ILanguageSpecificContainer<BlogEntryLS>
{
    public ICollection<BlogEntryLS> LanguageSpecificItems { get; set; }
```

So, yet I access an `Account` item and want to call `GetLocalizedPart`. e.g.:

```
db.Account.Include("CommentEmailAbonnements")
          .Include("CommentEmailAbonnements.LanguageSpecificItems")
          .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id = ...)
          .CommentEmailAbonnements.FirstOrDefault()
          .GetLocalizedPart();
```

Comment: Going to need to see more code. How is MyDbSet being generated. What types of calling parameters or types are included. Where did the string come from, was it hardcoded? Please expand your question a little to make it answerable. Short answer: reflection. Long answer: need more info.

Comment: @TravisJ I extended my question with some code pieces. I hope it is all neccessary code you Need to help me

Comment: Have you tried adding the virtual keyword to the 'LanguageSpecificItems' property of your BlogEntry class?